# Android 5.0+ New SD Card Access API DocumentFile.renameTo() UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, android-sdcard, file-rename, android-external-storage

I've been struggling on how to rename a DocumentFile on Lollipop.
I'm sorry I had tried to search everywhere for the solution, but there seems to be lack of the information online about this new SD Card Access API.

Here is what I have:

```
        String EditText = (Alert_EditText.getText().toString()).trim();
        Uri uri = ListViewObject_List.get(LastItemPos).getImageUri();
        final DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(MainClass.this, uri);
        documentFile.renameTo(EditText);
```

It came up with an UnsupportedOperationException:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.camera.test, PID: 3362
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at android.support.v4.provider.SingleDocumentFile.renameTo(SingleDocumentFile.java:105)
at com.camera.test.MainClass$21.onClick(MainClass.java:986)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5242)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10530)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21185)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I also have tried this:

```
    String EditText = (Alert_EditText.getText().toString()).trim();
    Uri uri = ListViewObject_List.get(LastItemPos).getImageUri();
    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
    final DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
    documentFile.renameTo(EditText);
```

It didn't seem to do anything: no error, nothing happened...

....

....
I can delete the DocumentFile just fine with the following:

```
Uri uri = ListViewObject_List.get(LastItemPos).getImageUri();
final DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(MainClass.this, uri);
documentFile.delete();
```

Can someone please take a look at it and see what I have done wrong?

Thank you very much for your kindness and help.

**Update:** this uri is

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3APictures%2FTest1/document/0000-0000%3APictures%2FTest1%2FMyPicture.jpg
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`renameTo()` is not supported for a `DocumentFile` created from `fromSingleUri()`.

You can try `DocumentsContract.renameDocument(getContentResolver(), uri, theNewDisplayName)`. `getContentResolver()` is a method on `Context` to get a `ContentResolver`. Note that this changes the display name; the interpretation of "display name" is up to the document provider. Also, not all providers support the renaming of documents, and so this may or may not work.

Note that the Storage Access Provider is not an "SD Card Access API". It is a document API. Those documents come from a document provider of the user's choosing, which may or may not involve removable storage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  So basically, I have to loop through the parent directory to look for the file that I am trying to delete.  Ehh, wouldn't that take a while when I have over 200000 of images?  I have no clue about the DocumentsProvider.Contract.  can you explain it a little more?  That sucks that I can't use documentFile.renameTo()  :-(

Comment: @Dante: My mistake. I was actually looking at the `DocumentProvider` class, which is wrong (that's the implementation of a document provider). `DocumentContract` has a `renameDocument()` method that you can try -- see my corrected answer.

Comment: Awesome, you are just genius!  I spent days trying to figure it out and searching online.  I can't thank you enough my friend.  Thank you very much for your knowledge and help!

Comment: How to delete file from SD Card in android KitKat and above?

Comment: In fact, due to missing documentation from Google, only a look at the Android source code can clarify things. **DocumentFile** is an abstract class, and the objects of this class are **SingleDocumentFile** or **TreeDocumentFile**. The first one's createFile(), createDirectory(), renameTo() and listFiles() operations throw an exception.
Additionally there is a **RawDocumentFile** that encapsulates a standard _File_ object.

Comment: Addendum: Both fromSingleUri() and fromTreeUri() set the parent to null. Thus the getParentFile() method is not really helpful.

Comment: @CommonsWare After `DocumentsContract.renameDocument()` invoked I don't have write permission anymore, I need to rename and then write data, is such way exists?

Comment: @PavelPoley: I have not used `renameDocument()` before, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, *createFile()*, *createDirectory()*, *renameTo()* and *listFiles()* operations throw an exception on objects created by *fromSingleUri()*.

Especially a single file, provided as Uri, cannot be renamed, even if the program already had been granted respective write permission. This is a design flaw.

Further, the mentioned function *DocumentsContract.renameDocument()* failed in all my tests, so I do not know what is was designed for.

However, I found a solution that is rather complicated, and it's based on granted document tree permissions:

1. Request for permissions with the usual ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE method.
2. Take permissions using *grantUriPermission()* and *takePersistableUriPermission()*.
3. Whenever your receive a SingleDocumentUri later, get the stored permission URIs using *getPersistedUriPermissions().*
4. Loop through the permissions and skip all those with not matching authority and whose first component is not "tree", but "document".
5. Check if the second component of the permission is a prefix of the second component of your SingleDocumentFile. If yes, you already have been granted the necessary permission.
6. Once you found a matching permission, create a TreeDocumentFile from it and walk with *findFile()* up the tree until you found your document. The path component separators can be "/" or ":" and maybe also others. It might be necessary to test the method with different Document Providers.
7. The last *findFile()* will give you a matching TreeDocumentFile with parent etc. which can be used for renaming.

In case you did not find a matching tree in your permissions, you might ask the user for granting the missing permissions, i.e. step 1.

Notes:

In case you call *fromTreeUri()* for an arbitrary directory URI you might get a TreeDocumentFile, but not for the respective directory, but for a directory below you already have permissions for. So after calling *fromTreeUri()* you might also walk up the tree, calling findFile() until you reach the directory you want to access.

I also experimented with *DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri()* but the result was not usable, i.e. I got a TreeDocumentUri but still could not rename the file.

This is all very strange, and its behaviour might result from the fact that you will never get a DocumentFile with parent, unless you walk through the tree manually.

If anybody finds a more elegant solution, just tell!